# Excluding notes using html_nodes() in r

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am scraping stock market prices using the `rvest` package in R. I would like to exclude nodes when using `html_nodes()`.

The following classes appear on the website with stock prices:
`[4] <span id="ctl00_ctl00_Content_LeftContent_IssueList_StockList_repIssues_ctl02_DifferenceBlock_lblRelativeDifferenceDown" class="ValueDown">-0,51%</span>
 [5] <span id="ctl00_ctl00_Content_LeftContent_IssueList_StockList_repIssues_ctl02_ctl02_lblDifference" class="ValueDown Difference">-51%</span>`

Now I would like to include only the text after `class="ValueDown"`, and I would like to exclude the text after `class="ValueDown Difference"`.

For this I use the following code:

```
urlIEX <- "https://www.iex.nl/Koersen/Europa_Lokale_Beurzen/Amsterdam/AMX.aspx"
webpageIEX <- read_html(urlIEX)

percentage_change <- webpageIEX %>%
  html_nodes(".ValueDown") %>%
  html_text()
```

However, this gives me both the values -0,51% and -51%. Is there a way to include everything with `class="ValueDown"` and exclude everything with `class="ValueDown Difference"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'am not expert, but I think you should use the attribute selector:

```
percentage_change <- webpageIEX %>%
  html_nodes("[class='ValueDown']") %>%
  html_text()
```